# Getting _query error while using KendoGrid and Kendo Chart

Tags: kendo-ui

We are getting following error while page load for the first time when we are using kendoGrid and KendoChart.

**‘Object doesn't support property or method '_query' in kendo.data.min.js file'**

Can anyone tell whats the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use jquery.min.js & kendo.web.min.js files. This might do the magic, if not let me know further requirement.